Clarity on Policy based Authorization in Razor Views
I have the following Razor page:
[Authorize(Policy = ClaimsPolicies.ViewAdminClaim)]
[BindProperties]
public class EditCompanyModel(ApplicationDbContext applicationDbContext) : PageModel

where the policy comes from a constant:
public const string ViewAdminClaim = "View Admin Claim";

My startup has this to add the claims:
_ = services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(ClaimsPolicies.ViewAdminClaim, policy => policy.RequireClaim(DefaultClaims.ViewAdminClaim, "Yes"));
});

My db looks like this:
UserRoles:



UserID
RoleID




778a23b9-807e-4289-a2b9-49e5f0921525
a31dd068-1c7b-48a5-97e9-a6340031fbe4



Roles:



ID
Name
NormalizedName
ConcurrencyStamp




a31dd068-1c7b-48a5-97e9-a6340031fbe4
Sys Admin
SYS ADMIN
84cc866a-0087-41a9-b5e4-1d106f2ee851



RoleClaims:



ID
RoleID
ClaimType
ClaimValue




1
a31dd068-1c7b-48a5-97e9-a6340031fbe4
View Admin Claim
Yes



After signing in debugger, my claims are registered in the below Claims Principal:
await _signInManager.Context.SignInAsync(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme, claimsPrincipal);
as {View Admin Claim: Yes}, however if I try to visit the EditCompany Page, I am met with 403 Unauthorized.
Is there a check that I am missing?
Below is my LoginAsync:
public async Task<Response> LoginAsync(CookieRequest request)
{
    ApplicationUser? user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(request.Email);

    if (user == null)
    {
        return Response.Fail("Invalid user");
    }

    if (user.IsActive == false)
    {
        return Response.Fail("User account deactivated");
    }

    bool passwordIsCorrect = await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, request.Password);

    if (!passwordIsCorrect)
    {
        return Response.Fail("Incorrect Password");
    }

    Claim[] customClaims = [
            new Claim("tenant", user.TenantId)
        ];

    ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal = await _signInManager.CreateUserPrincipalAsync(user);
    if (claimsPrincipal.Identity is ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity)
    {
        claimsIdentity.AddClaims(customClaims);
    }


    await _signInManager.Context.SignInAsync(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme, claimsPrincipal);


    return Response.Success();
}

and my Page Model:
 [AllowAnonymous]
 public class LoginModel : PageModel
 {
     public CookieRequest cookieRequest { get; set; }

     public IActionResult OnGet()
     {
         return User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ? Redirect("/") : Page();
     }
 }

My claimsPrinicipal holds the below claims on debug breakpoint:
"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier: 778a23b9-807e-4289-a2b9-49e5f0921525"
"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name: admin@admin.com.test"
"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress: admin@admin.com"
"AspNet.Identity.SecurityStamp: PJHVEWTBNDUGPV5ONJAR776VO5W6JOF7"
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role: Sys Admin"
"View Admin Claim: Yes"
"tenant: test"

Addition, segment of my Program.cs:
app.UseCors("defaultPolicy");
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/NotFound");
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseMiddleware<TenantResolver>();
app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
app.MapControllers();
app.UseSession();
app.Run();


If you can make sure your RoleClaims table contains correct role with claims like what you shared, you jsut need sign in by code:
await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(username, password, true, lockoutOnFailure: false);

instead of:
await _signInManager.Context.SignInAsync(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme, claimsPrincipal);

Then ensure that authentication middleware (app.UseAuthentication()) comes before authorization middleware (app.UseAuthorization()).
If you must use _signInManager.Context.SignInAsync, the working code shoule be like:
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string username, string password)
{
    var user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(username);
    if (user != null && await _signInManager.CheckPasswordSignInAsync(user, password, false) == Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInResult.Success)
    {
        var claims = new List<Claim>
    {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username),
        new Claim("View Admin Claim","Yes")    //be sure add this line
    };

        var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme);
        var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);    
        await _signInManager.Context.SignInAsync(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme, claimsPrincipal);

        return RedirectToPage("/WelcomeEmail");
    }

    return Page();
}


Hi Rena, Thank you for the feedback. I have added my current LoginAsync and LoginPageModel to my original question to expand on the information.

Hi @Sanjeev-e-jeevs, pls share your Program.cs or Startup.cs, ensure that authentication middleware (app.UseAuthentication()) comes before authorization middleware (app.UseAuthorization()).

Hi @Sanjeev-e-jeevs, according to your shared Program.cs, it seems you use Blazor? Pls share the version and which is your detailed teamplate, Blazor Server or Blazor WebAssembly.
